# TicTacToe game board kata, Not sure why this isn't working for random inputs

Tags: python

So the input should accept a list of characters eg. ["X","O"," ", "X", "X", "X] and divide that by n e.g. 3. The output should be:
X | O |
(dashes here ---)
X X X

and it works on most tests, but seems to fail when integers are involved. I'm a beginner so I've been debugging with Thonny, and can't understand where or why it's failing and skipping it when it shows numbers.

```
def display_board(board, width):
    newboard = []
      ## 1. loop through board first, start at 0 because we're referencing the first position
    for xo in range (0, len(board), width):
      ## 2. only take width as in number of characters first to xodivs
        xodivs = board[xo:xo + width]
        separator = " | " #this is what you will use between chars
      ## 3. create a new board that is joined by separator
        newlines = separator.join(xodivs)
        newboard.append(newlines)
       #####OKAY THIS WORKS! 

      ## 4. now append these strings to a new text block bish
    final_board = []
    for xsandos in newboard:
        final_board.append(" " + xsandos + " ")
        if xsandos != newboard[-1]: #number of lines -1 bec in dividing inbetween only
    ## 5. NOW loop through the board you just made and separate it by dashes
            dashes = "\n" + ("-" * (len(newlines) +2)) + "\n"
            final_board.append(dashes)
    return "".join(final_board)
```

I've tried changing the formatting, this works with alphanumeric characters but not integers. it should theoretically work for both

EDIT:
This code seems to work:

```
def display_board(board, width):
    newboard = []
      ## 1. loop through board first, start at 0 because we're referencing the first position
    for xo in range (0, len(board), width):
      ## 2. only take width as in number of characters first to xodivs
        xodivs = board[xo:xo + width]
        separator = " | " #this is what you will use between chars
      ## 3. create a new board that is joined by separator
        newlines = separator.join(xodivs)
        newboard.append(newlines)
       #####OKAY THIS WORKS! 

      ## 4. now append these strings to a new text block bish
    final_board = []
    for i,xsandos in enumerate(newboard):
        final_board.append(" " + xsandos + " ")
        if i != len(newboard)-1: #number of lines -1 bec in dividing inbetween only
## 5. NOW loop through the board you just made and separate it by dashes
            dashes = "\n" + ("-" * (len(newlines) +2)) + "\n"
            final_board.append(dashes)
    return "".join(final_board)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: input: displayboard(["X","O","X","X","X","O","X","X","X"], 3)
expected output:>>> 
 X | O | X
 X | X | O
 X | X | O

This code works fine for these characters and strings. It was giving errors for inputs like:
display_board(["1","2","3","4"], 2) 
expected output:
>>
 1 | 2
 3 | 4

Actual:
1 | 2 | 3 | 4

But I think i found how to do it! editing post now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> it should theoretically work for both

Not really, `str.join` method is expecting an iterable full of strings as input.

See: [*Documentation*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

You can convert integers to string using built-in function `str` :

```py
newlines = separator.join(map(str, xodivs))
```